# How to use C# to create User with Alias in Google Admin SDK Directory?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

So I have some code that works, mostly. I am able to create a user with the Google Admin SDK Directory API but the alias that I specify does not get created for the user. What am I doing wrong? Is it a separate operation(like a patchrequest?) to create an alias for an account? I'm not getting any errors, the alias simply is not there after I've created the account.

```
UsersResource.InsertRequest user = this.service.Users.Insert(new User
{
    PrimaryEmail = this.pid + "@" + Domain,
    Name = new UserName
    {
        GivenName = this.usedfname,
        FamilyName = this.lname,
        FullName = this.usedfullname,
    },
    Aliases = new List<string>()
    {
        this.usedfname + "." + this.lname + "@" + Domain,
    },

    Password = this.password,

});
user.Execute();
```

FYI, this is a part of a class. An example of creating an alias in c# would be very helpful but I can't seem to find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a user and aliases in one API call. You need to create the user and then call [users.aliases.insert()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/insert)

Comment: Sure enough. This is what i ended up with                UsersResource.AliasesResource.InsertRequest alias = this.service.Users.Aliases.Insert(new Alias {  
                        
                           AliasValue = this.usedfname + "." + this.lname + "@" + Domain,
                        },this.pid+"@"+Domain);
                alias.Execute();